# Symfony form emty_value and multiple

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a "teachers" field in a form.
I would like to be able to select a blank value.

But in the symfony doc, I read that I have to set the multiple to false and the required to false, to add an empty_value and an empty_data. I understand the required. But why is this necessary to set the multiple to false ?

How can I add an empty_value with a multiple => true field ?

Here is my builder :

```
$builder->add('teachers', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'Ent\UserBundle\Entity\User',
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
        $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('u.group', '\'ROLE_TEACHER\''));

        return $qb;
    }
]);
```

Comment: What happens if you add both? Do you get any errors, or it just simply does not work?

Comment: That does not work, and if I set multiple to false, I can see my empty_value...

Comment: There must be a good reason why they don't let you do this, but as a last resort you can always write a custom form type that inherits from choice and overrides this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant specify at the same time `multiple` and `empty_value`. Because `multiple` mean that you have got checkboxes at form or select with multiple choices. In the first case, you can uncheck all checkboxes and recieve empty array, in second you can do the same with ctrl button.

[symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-value)

Comment: cant understand how could you choose empty value with multiple options... You want to select 2 teachers and empty one? What it will mean?

Comment: I just want an option that clearly means that I want no teacher. Exactly like a mutiple => false... Submit the form without select a prof sounds like a trick for me.

Comment: You can add button that will unselect all options via javascript for example.

Comment: Ok Thanks forgottenbas, if there is no way with the builder, I will definitively be using some javascript...